# MS Access 2007 - Changing a checkbox to be unchecked

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an unbound text box that I want to enter a number in and then it would go in a form.  When I do this, I want to change the status of checkbox in another form as well.  So it is like inventory.  When I add this item to this box, I need the checkbox value to change because it's no longer in inventory.  So the form I have is 'Info' and the checkbox is named 'ChkboxAvailableUse'.  I have the checkbox correlated to a kit number and location and stuff too.  So when I enter the number in an unbound text box called 'AssignKit', I want that number to look for the same kit number the 'Info' form and the 'InvKitNumber' text field, and then change that records checkbox (ChkboxAvailableUse) to change to false.  I hope this makes sense.  I have the line of code I thought would work below.  Any help would be fantastic.  Thank you

```
CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE Info SET ChkboxAvailableUse = FALSE WHERE InvKitNumber = " & Me.AssignKit & ""
```

Comment: What error does this give you?  And if I were to do it I would pull the record with a recordset and set the check box that way.  But then again I'm unfamiliar with `CurrentDb.Execute`.

Comment: @TKEyi60, Right now it says there is a Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'InvKitNumber='.  Could you elaborate on pulling the record with a recordset?

Comment: try adding single quotes to `WHERE InvKitNumber = '" & Me.AssignKit & "'"`

Comment: Also, are you trying to change information in the table you have created based on info in the form?  Or are you just using this form or subform to update a different field on that form?

Comment: I added the quotes, it did something.  Now it says I have 2 few parameters. And right now I have multiple tables, and one table being info.  I have many records in this table and now all of the checkboxes are checked.  I made a form, and have an Info subform, which contains the information from the Info table.  That is what I am trying to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want that form to uncheck or check in the table to match your form or subfrom then you could use a recordset.

```
Dim myR as Recordset
Dim strSQL as String

'This SELECT string will pull from the assignkit field in the subform 
'and will be used find the matching record in the table
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE InvKitNumber = '" & Me!subformnamehere.Form.AssignKit & "'"

'This will make your recordeset variable the one record you want to modify
Set myR = db.OpendRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

'Now that the recordset is pointing to that row, you can change the checkbox
'with something like this, and even use an IF statement
myR.Edit
myR![ChkboxAvailable] = True 
myR.Update

'Then close the recordeset when done
Set myR = Nothing
```

I hope this helps, let me know if you need me to tweek it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I still get a problem however. First, where you wrote '" & Me!subformnamehere.Form.AssignKit & "'" I think should be different.  This is an unbound text box that I just have on the main form and isn't inside of a subform.  My main form contains 3 subforms all around, and then some unbound text boxes, which one includes is 'AssignKit' and it isn't attached to any subform.  So I changed it to Me!AssignKit.  I'm not sure if that is right though.  Second, when I changed it to that, I then recieved and error on the line below that (Set myR = ...) claiming "Object required"

Comment: You're correct.  The main form should just be `Me!AssignKit` if the name of the text box is AssignKit.  Or you can use `Me.AssignKit`.  I prefer using the periods, but that's just me.  Try commenting out the `WHERE .....` and after to see if you can set the recordset to the whole table.  So it should look like `strSQL = "SELECT * FROM info"` and make sure that the table name is capitalized and spelled correctly

Comment: So I changed some stuff around and get a different error. It says "Too few parameters: Expected 1" and then when I go into debug it yellow highlights this line "Set myR = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)". What do you think that could be?

Answer (score 0):

The sql UPDATE statement updates fields in a table. Tables don't have checkboxes, forms do, and I assume that the field (in the table) is not called **ChkboxAvailableUse** ?

If the field is named AvailableUse then you would update this field with:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Info SET AvailableUse = FALSE WHERE InvKitNumber = " & Me.AssignKit
```

Then you could `ReQuery` the (other) form (or a control on the form) so that it reflects these changes.

Comment: I have tables that I made.  The 'Info' table that I made has 4 fields and 2 of them have checkboxes.  So when I designed a form, I created a subform of 'Info' which is how there are checkboxes.  So yes it is now a form that has the checkbox.  So I named the checkbox that I want to change 'ChkboxAvailableUse'.  I tried what you gave me.  But I get a syntax error now on (missing operator) in query expression 'InvKitNumber='.